# Control Animator after asset bundle load from server?

Tags: unity-game-engine, assetbundle, animator

I create the **asset bundle** that has my model and animations, but after I fetch the asset bundle from the server I can't control the animations by **SetTrigger()** so I can see the **animator** in right place in the model but it doesn't work.

```
GameObject modelBundle = bundle.LoadAsset<GameObject>(jsonModelName);
modelBundleInstantiate = Instantiate(modelBundle);
//.....
_currentAnaimator = modelBundleInstantiate.GetComponentInChildren<Animator>();
_currentAnaimator.SetTrigger("Next"); // NOT WORK when click the button.
```

Comment: Is `_currentAnaimator` public? Try to make it a public variable in your script / class. Then you can see if the Component is loaded properly. Perhaps `GetComponentInChildren` returns `null` ? Where is the script attached? Why are you searching for the component in children?

Comment: I put the _currentAnaimator as public and I make sure the SieveAnalysis(Clone) Animator(model) is correct, but still, I can't move using SetTrigger